# Unable to concat more than 4k char in a mybatis query

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, jaxb, mybatis

> Problems gist:

1. Problem 1:

   - I have few variables(too big..few 2K each) which needs to be
     concatinated to a final content.Which is a list of lists intern.
     Oracle concat is unable to concat more than 4k, causing me too long concat exception
2. Problem 2:

   - When i tried to solve problem 1, by getting those variables into java
     VO(ValueObject) and concat into a java string. The problem is that I have a
     InstructionType list and AdditionalInfo sublist which is created by
     this query2, where I was unable to set multiple rows to a single
     string. Tried to have string arraylist.

**

> Problem 1 Description:

**
I have a mybatis query, looks some thing like this.

```
<select id="xyz" parameterType="com.test.VO" resultMap="abc" fetchSize="100" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY">
        select tag.TAG_desc TAGNAME,
           (det.tag_val_1 || det.tag_val_2 || det.tag_val_3 || det.tag_val_4 ||
           det.tag_val_5 || det.tag_val_6 || det.tag_val_7 || det.tag_val_8 ||
           det.tag_val_9 || det.tag_val_10) TAGVALUE,
           det.tag_no||lpad(det.sub_fld, 2, '0') TAGID
      from A det, B tag
       where det.brch_code = #{branchCode}
       and det.prod_ref_id = #{refId}
       and det.tnx_id= #{tnxId}
       and det.msg_type= #{messageNumber}
       and det.msg_type = tag.msg_type
       and (det.tag_no = tag.tag_no or substr(det.tag_no, 0, 2) = tag.tag_no )
       and (det.tag_no = rpad(tag.tag_no, 3, '_') )
       and det.tag_val_1 is not null
    </select>
    <resultMap id="abc" type="com.test.InstructionType$AdditionalInfo">                 
                <result property="name" column="TAGNAME" />
                <result property="id"   column="TAGID" />
                <result property="content"      column="TAGVALUE" />
    </resultMap>
```

It is giving me below error:

```
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [1489]; ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

The tag_val_1 to tag_val_10 can have upto 2K chars, which caused the above issue.

> Problem 2 Description:

Tried to get the tag_val's to the ValueObject(VO) and concat in java.

Looks some thing like

```
<select id="XYZ" parameterType="com.test.OutboundInterfaceVO" resultMap="abc" fetchSize="100" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY">
        select tag.TAG_desc TAGNAME,
           (det.tag_val_1||det.tag_val_2)TAGVAL12,
           (det.tag_val_3||det.tag_val_4 )TAGVAL34,
           (det.tag_val_5||det.tag_val_6  )TAGVAL56,
           (det.tag_val_7||det.tag_val_8||det.tag_val_9 || det.tag_val_10) TAGVALUE710,
      from A det, B tag
       where det.brch_code = #{branchCode}
       and det.prod_ref_id = #{refId}
       and det.tnx_id= #{tnxId}
       and det.msg_type= #{messageNumber}
       and det.msg_type = tag.msg_type
       and (det.tag_no = tag.tag_no or substr(det.tag_no, 0, 2) = tag.tag_no )
       and (det.tag_no = rpad(tag.tag_no, 3, '_') )
       and det.tag_val_1 is not null
    </select>
      <resultMap id="abc" type="com.test.OutboundInterfaceVO">
            <result property="tagName" column="TAGNAME" />
            <result property="tagId"   column="TAGID" />
            <result property="tagVal12"      column="TAGVAL12" />
            <result property="tagVal34"      column="TAGVAL34" />
            <result property="tagVal56"      column="TAGVAL56" />
            <result property="tagVal710"      column="TAGVAL710" />
</resultMap>
```

case1>Tried thinking that it was returning a row(My Bad)

```
  private String tagName;
    private String tagId;
    private String tagVal12;
    private String tagVal34;
    private String tagVal56;
    private String tagVal710;
```

Case2>As the query returned sucessfully, without that ORA error(Checked in PL/SQL Dev)

The problem is in the resultmap, this time.

There are about 30 rows returned, tried to catch them as a list of strings,

```
 private List<String[]> tagName = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String[]> tagId = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String[]> tagVal12 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String[]> tagVal34 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String[]> tagVal56 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String[]> tagVal710 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

With the looping as below in java.

```
List<InstructionType> instructionList = mapper.pqr(interfaceVO);
        for (InstructionType instructionType : instructionList) {
------
mapper.XYZ(VO);
  for (InstructionType.AdditionalInfo addlist : instructionType.getAdditionalInfo()) 
                {
                    addlist.setID(interfaceVO.getTagId());
                    addlist.setName(interfaceVO.getTagName());
                    content.append(interfaceVO.getTagVal12());
                    content.append(interfaceVO.getTagVal34());
                    content.append(interfaceVO.getTagVal56());
                    content.append(interfaceVO.getTagVal710());
                    addlist.setContent(content.toString());
                }
        }

      instructionDetails.getInstruction().addAll(instructionList);
```

My InstructionType class, would help a bit

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "InstructionType", namespace = "http://www.db.com/tf", propOrder = {
            "additionalInfo"
    })
    public class InstructionType {
     @XmlElement(name = "AdditionalInfo", namespace = "http://www.abc.com/tf")
        protected List<InstructionType.AdditionalInfo> additionalInfo;
    ...along with setters and getters 
     public static class AdditionalInfo {

            @XmlValue
            protected String content;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
            protected String name;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "ID")
            protected String id;


    .....along with setters and getter in each class

    }
}
```

> Note: I have mybatis 3.2.2 and Oracle 11g, java 6

Stuck there guys, Any sort of help in solving problem1 which avoids problem2 would be great.
Else, please help me out in setting list of lists in a better way.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you not use a CLOB or BLOB column instead? JDBC have good support for them.

Comment: thought of them...did not try... let me give it a try

Comment: NO @billc.cn my tables are predefined and i'm not allowed to change them...

Comment: You might want to try this: http://nimishgarg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/ora-01489-result-of-string.html, i.e. convert the first varchar to clob and then concatenate the rest onto it. Remember the return type will be Clob instead of String.

Comment: @billc.cn tried this too.... `ORA 24813: Cannot send or recieve an unsupported lob` was the exception i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.... Found that the solution provided to problem 1 was returning 30 rows rather than 1 ...
But I was setting it into one String variable...!!(My Bad)

Thanks everyone for your support..!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error from the Oracle DB. This is unrelated to mybatis. The error message is pretty clear.
If I were you, I'd simply do the string concatenation within Java rather than in SQL.

Comment: Actually its possible to use stored function to concatenate your string into CLOB and return result as a value. But its much easer and faster to use java string builder.

Comment: Any views on using CONCAT() ?

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE``abc``(IN tagVal12 VARCHAR, IN tagVal34 VARCHAR, IN tagVal56 VARCHAR, IN tagVal710 VARCHAR) BEGIN SELECT CONCAT(tagVal12,tagVal34,tagVal56,tagVal710); END; | call abc(tagVal12,tagVal34,tagVal56,tagVal710);`